# Spark repartition to specific resources

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given a Spark cluster with a mix of machine types (e.g. with and without GPU).  I want to run a Spark pipeline where some stages run on machines with no GPU and some stags with GPU

I'm open to using any cluster manager (YARN, Kubernetes, Mesos, etc..)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val cpu_only = udf((v: String) => v)
val gpu_only = udf((v: String) => v)

val dataset = Seq((0, "hello"), (1, "world")).toDF("id", "text")

dataset
  .withColumn("from_cpu", cpu_only('text))
  .withColumn("from_gpu", gpu_only('from_cpu))
  .show

/* conceptual need "repartitionToResourcePool" (which doesn't exist)
  dataset
      .repartitionToResourcePool("CPU_ONLY")
      .withColumn("from_cpu", cpu_only('text))
      .repartitionToResourcePool("GPU_ONLY")
      .withColumn("from_gpu", gpu_only('from_cpu))
      .show
  */
```

In the case above, the the cpu_only UDF code should only be executed on machines with no GPU and gpu_only should only be executed on machines with GPUs

Any pointers on how to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Have you seen [this presentation](https://databricks.com/session/gpu-support-in-spark-and-gpu-cpu-mixed-resource-scheduling-at-production-scale) by IBM?

Comment: Thanks Hristo!  This is a very nice link and close to what I'm looking for.  I'm hoping for something open source (or DIY) and potentially more general than gpu vs. no gpu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this with just a bit of customization to Spark.

Two basic changes

1. Add new RDD to allow manually setting preferredLocations.
2. Add ability to mark a preferredLocations as fixed.  This prevents the scheduler from using Workers that aren't in the preferredLocations list

Code is available on github [spark-fixed-location](https://github.com/BrianHuf/spark-fixed-location)

Example usage

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val cpu_only = udf((v: String) => v)
val gpu_only = udf((v: String) => v)

val dataset = Seq((0, "hello"), (1, "world")).toDF("id", "text")

import example.extend_spark_api._ // NEW

val cpu = sc.getWorkersFromTag("CPU") // NEW
val gpu = sc.getWorkersFromTag("GPU") // NEW

dataset
  .repartitionTo(cpu) // NEW
  .withColumn("from_cpu", cpu_only('text))
  .repartitionTo(gpu) // NEW
  .withColumn("from_gpu", gpu_only('from_cpu))
  .show
```